# Integrating First Data (previously YourPay and LinkPoint) payment gateway with custom ASP booking system

Tags: com, asp-classic, payment-gateway

I’m trying to integrate a simple booking system (developed in ASP) with this payment gateway: https://www.firstdata.com/

My site is hosted on a shared server and I was hoping to pass the transaction details to firstdata and have all the secure data entered and processed on their system (as in a Form Purchase token type model).

However, I'm having trouble ascertaining whether that's possible on Firstdata, the documentation is complicated and I'm not getting much response from their technical support. Ideally I'd like a test store integration example, but I can't find this on their site.

Does anyone have any experience of integrating this payment gateway using ASP, and if so any help they can offer?

Many thanks,

Lucy

Comment: sorry - not sure whether I should have edited the above questions rather than answer my own question below?

Answer (score 2):

FirstData is the worst for support and integration.

I have experience w/ integrating them w/ perl, so that probably doesn't help much, sorry. But just letting you know its basically trial and error, there tech support is of no help.

Comment: True, their classic ASP support stunk 4 years ago as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the LinkPoint and YourPay gateways.  Both required a COM object, so a DLL must be installed on the server.  Is your host willing to install that DLL and incur a possible reboot for your site, or do they already have it installed?

If they have it installed, there will be sample .asp integration examples from FirstData, but you have to sign up for a developer account.  Once you get their example and if you have any further questions on how to do it, please update your question here and we will work through it.